# How to get value from other function - PHP

Tags: php, oop

I'm putting the Google Analytics API codes in the form of OOP, I've created access classes, but I'm having trouble accessing the variables returned by each function. For example:

I have the function `initializeAnalytics ();`in my `access` class.

```
function initializeAnalytics(){

$KEY_FILE_LOCATION = __DIR__ . '/service-account-credentials.json';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("xxxxxx");
$client->setAuthConfig($KEY_FILE_LOCATION);
$client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']);
// $client->setRedirectUri($this->_redirectURI);
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setApprovalPrompt('force');
$analytics = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);

return $analytics;
}
```

After I have the class `AccessAnalytics ();`

```
function acessaAnalytics(){
        global $results;
        $analytics = new access();
        $analytics->initializeAnalytics();
        $this->getFirstProfileId();
        $results = getResults($analytics, $profile);
        return $results;
    }
```

And finally the class `getFirstProfileId ();`

```
function getFirstProfileId($analytics) {

    $accounts = $analytics->management_accounts->listManagementAccounts();

    if (count($accounts->getItems()) > 0) {
        $items = $accounts->getItems();
        $firstAccountId = $items[0]->getId();

        // Get the list of properties for the authorized user.
        $properties = $analytics->management_webproperties
            ->listManagementWebproperties($firstAccountId);

        if (count($properties->getItems()) > 0) {
          $items = $properties->getItems();
          $firstPropertyId = $items[0]->getId();

          // Get the list of views (profiles) for the authorized user.
          $profiles = $analytics->management_profiles
              ->listManagementProfiles($firstAccountId, $firstPropertyId);

          if (count($profiles->getItems()) > 0) {
            $items = $profiles->getItems();

            // Return the first view (profile) ID.
            return $items[0]->getId();

          } else {
            throw new Exception('No views (profiles) found for this user.');
          }
        } else {
          throw new Exception('No properties found for this user.');
        }
      } else {
        throw new Exception('No accounts found for this user.');
      }

      return $items;
    }
```

The question is, how do you get these values between the functions that complement each other? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Set them as global variables so you will use them in every function just by calling them.

2)Return the variable from the function:
return $analytics;
and assign it when you call the function:
$NewVariable = initializeAnalytics();

Those are the 2 solutions i can think of this issue.